# How to shuffle and merge two dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, logic

I have two dictionaries with different lengths. I want to shuffle both the dictionaries and merge them.I am stuck at writing logic for the same I need some help with algorithm.

first dict

```
a = { 
'key1' : {'video1' : 'url1'}, 
'key2' : {'video2' : 'url2'}, 
'key3' : {'video3' : 'url3'}
}
```

second dict

```
b = {'ad_video1' : 'url1', 'ad_video2' : 'url2'}
```

Desired output is

```
c = {
    'key1': {
        'video1' : 'url1',
        'ad_video1' : 'url1'

    }, 
    'key2': {
        'video2' : 'url2',
        'ad_video2' : 'url2'
    }, 
    'key3': {
        'video3' : 'url3',
        'ad_video1' : 'url1'
    }
}
```

How can I get that final merged dict? 
Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered in python, so I'm not sure what you mean by shuffling them?

Comment: Why do you want to end up with `'ad_video1' : 'url2'` in the final dictionary? this pair doesn't appear in `b`.

Comment: Why does the output have `'ad_video1' : 'url1'` in the `'key3'` sub-dict?

Comment: Where do you get ad_video3 and url3 from?

Comment: @PM2Ring i need it. Understand it this way basically i have a 2 list of videos one is  the health based videos and the other one is list of ad's videos  and I want to play ads before each video and all the ads should be assigned to all the health based videos. I am having trouble finding the logic Thanks

Comment: @MushroomMauLa there is no ad_video3 in it. Thanks

Comment: But that still doesn't explain why `'ad_video1' : 'url1'` is in the `'key3'`  sub-dict. Why isn't it `'ad_video2' : 'url2'`, or something else? It's pretty hard to write code that does what you want if you can't explain the logic. Remember that Python dictionaries are unordered, as mvr said 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @PM2Ring could be 'ad_video2' also it should restart assigning videos from start once the dict is exhausted

Comment: Dictionaries don't _have_ a start: they are unordered. But you can impose an order, eg by sorting the keys in some way. If you want to do that then you need to say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that I believe does what you want. It imposes an order onto the dictionaries by sorting the key strings. We can cycle over the keys in the `b` dict using [`cycle` from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

```
from itertools import chain, cycle
from pprint import pprint

a = { 
    'key1': {'video1' : 'url1'},
    'key2': {'video2' : 'url2'},
    'key3': {'video3' : 'url3'}
}

b = {'ad_video1': 'url1', 'ad_video2': 'url2'}

c = {}
for k1, k2 in zip(sorted(a.keys()), cycle(sorted(b.keys()))):
    c[k1] = a[k1].copy()
    c[k1][k2] = b[k2]

pprint(c)
```

**output**

```
{'key1': {'ad_video1': 'url1', 'video1': 'url1'},
 'key2': {'ad_video2': 'url2', 'video2': 'url2'},
 'key3': {'ad_video1': 'url1', 'video3': 'url3'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following steps to merge two dictionaries
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
dct = {}
for key1,value1 in a.items():
    for key2,value2 in b.items():
        dct[key1] = value1
        if key2.endswith(key1[-1:]) and value2.endswith(key1[-1:]):
            dct.get(key1)[key2] = value2
```

Comment: thanks it works but it does't assign any ads to the remaining values in 'a' dict

Comment: Which ad_video's do you want to assign when they don't match? Always ad_video1?

Comment: First I don't want to match values I just want to assign random ad videos. Understand it this way basically i have a 2 list of videos one is the health based videos and the other one is list of ad's videos and I want to play ads before each video and all the ads should be assigned to all the health based videos. Thanks

Comment: So the ad vidoes you play before are always random?

Comment: Yes the are always random. Thanks